# Generics in java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I've opened java.util.ArrayList source code, and I can't understand one thing: why elementData[] array is of type Object if ArrayList is parametrized?

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends ... {
  .........
  private transient Object[] elementData;
  .........
  public boolean add(E e) {/*More code*/}
}
```

**Question**: Why don't define elementData as:

```
private transient E[] elementData
```

*what advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime that you create a List with raw type, like :

> List`<MyObject>` list = new ArrayList`<MyObject>`();

The contructor converts all data into a array that must be an Object[] array, on:

> public ArrayList(Collection`<? extends E>` c) {   elementData =
>   c.toArray(); ...

I think this happens because ArrayList can be initialized with no raw types, like on:

> List list = new ArrayList();

```
    list.add(new String("VALUE"));
    list.add(new Integer("1"));

    for (Object c : list) {
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
```

and you can put more than one type of object inside.

Also, ArrayList uses the

> Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);

to manage some operations, which will return an Object[].

You may also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776576/why-arraylist-implementation-uses-object) like Paul said.

Comment: this does not explain why it can't be `E[]`

Comment: I put this explanation on one of the links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776576/why-arraylist-implementation-uses-object

Comment: I know you linked to it at the end as "you may also take a look". But otherwise none of this is relevant to the question, which is, why not `E[]`